# Need help on RestTemplate exchange method

Tags: android, spring-boot, resttemplate

I need to do authentification from my app android by using spring boot i try to send the username and password like this:

```
HttpAuthentication authHeader = new HttpBasicAuthentication(username, password);
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setAuthorization(authHeader);
        requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

and make network request using restTemplate.exchange :

```
ResponseEntity<Message> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders), Message.class);
```

but i still get null response.

this my code server :

**Controller:**

```
@Controller  
public class RController {  

    @RequestMapping(value={"/welcome"})
    public @ResponseBody Message getMessage() { 
    return new Message(100, "Congratulations!", "You have accessed a Basic 
        Auth protected resource.");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/login"})
        public String login() {
        return "login";
    }  
}
```

**config**

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
            .permitAll();
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add `and().httpBasic()` to your `configure(...)` method

Comment: Thank u i'll try with it

Comment: still not working :/ ...any suggestion sir please

Answer (score 0):

I believe `RController` class would need to be annotated with `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`

Comment: you are right...I make the change but still not working...From my search I found that post need parameters to send for request network  I wonder how can I do it !

Comment: I would suggest to try to get the endpoint to work without security first, then add security

Comment: `@RestController` is just syntactic sugar for `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody' annotations. Because `@ResponseBody` annotation is already in place above the `getMessage()` method, your suggestion won't affect anything, except breaking `login()` method, which instead of view named login will return string value  'login'.

Comment: @ootero oki thank you...please if you have tutorials or documentation can help